# sum of items in a 2d list

Tags: list, python-3.x, 2d

Im trying ti implement a function evenrow() that takes a two dimensional list of integers and returns True if each row of the table sums up to an even number and False otherwise (i.e.., if some row sums up to an odd number)

```
    usage
    >>> evenrow([[1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 6]])
    True
    >>> evenrow([[1, 3], [3, 4], [0, 5]])
    False
```

This is what I got so far:

```
    def evenrow(lst):
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if sum(lst[i])%2==0:     # here is the problem, it only iterates over the first item in the lst [1, 3] - i cant figure this out - range problem?      
                return True
            else:
                False
```

How do I get the loop to iterate over every item [1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 6] in the list and not just the first?

well I have gotten this far now:

```
    def evenrow(lst):
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if sum(lst[i]) %2 >0:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

and i get the following answer when executing different lists:

```
     >>> evenrow([[1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 6]])
     True
     >>> evenrow([[1, 3], [3, 4], [0, 5]])
     False
     >>> evenrow([[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 7], [0, 6, 2]])
     True
     >>> evenrow([[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 7], [0, 5, 2]])
     True
```

(the last one is not correct though - should be False) I just dont get why this is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning too early. You should check for all the pairs, only returning `True` afterwards, or return `False` if a odd sum is encountered.

Spoiler alert:

```
def evenrow(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
       if sum(lst[i]) % 2 != 0:     # here is the problem, it only iterates over the first item in the lst [1, 3] - i cant figure this out - range problem?      
           return False
    return True
```

This will achieve the goal.

Comment: f sum(lst[i]) % 2 <>0: (invalid syntax <>)

Comment: it doesnt work for both these usages

         >>> evenrow([[1, 3], [3, 4], [0, 5]])
         False
         >>> evenrow([[1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 6]])
>>>        # empty

Comment: @Snarre Edited, was using python 2, might be the problem.